# Why do we see the prince stab Sophie if that didn't actually happen?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-illusionist

I just re-watched *The Illusionist*, but I looked up how she survived the stabbing from the prince.

Everyone says she drugged the prince, and that she faked the stabbing.

But we see the prince walking out of the house and stabs Sophie, and the guy in the house sees him call her a Whore, etc.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mistaken, we see everything through the point of view of the witness.

He sees:

- Sophie running into an alley, upset
- the drunken prince stumbling after her and shouting

Then we only hear the argument between them and the sound of a blade.

- Then we see her leaving on the horse, presumably lifeless.
- Then we see the horse returning home, alone and with blood on it
- Then Sophie's body is found in the water

At no point we *actually see* any actual stabbing being performed, we just *assumed* it happened based on what is shown to us.

The prince *was* probably drugged: we also see him and Sophie drinking before the fight. Everything was planned and arranged to look like a murder committed by the prince.

Comment: You're right, I got confused because I thought by drugging him, he collapsed on the floor or something. I didn't think he'd be able to chase her, at least very well.

Comment: @djbritt it all depends on the amount and the potency of whatever he drunk. Probably just strong enough or slow enough, combined with the alcohol.